# What does it mean to order a set?

Tags: alloy

When the ordering module is called with a set then all these functions are suddenly available on the set: `first, last, next, prev, etc.`

```
first returns the first atom.
last returns the last atom.
first.next returns the second atom.
```

But wait!

A set is, by definition, unordered. So how can you order a set?

Consider this set of colors:

```
abstract sig Color {}
one sig red extends Color {}
one sig yellow extends Color {}
one sig green extends Color {}
```

What does it mean to order that set of colors? Suppose we call the ordering module:

```
open util/ordering[Color]
```

What does `first` return? What does `last` return? What does `first.next` return?

Let’s have Alloy generate some instances:

```
run {}
```

Here are a few of the instances that are generated:

Instance #1

```
first returns: yellow
last returns: green
first.next returns: red
```

Instance #2

```
first returns: yellow
last returns: red
first.next returns: green
```

Instance #3

```
first returns: green
last returns: yellow
first.next returns: red
```

Notice that the ordering is different with each instance.

Now, let’s order a plain signature:

```
open util/ordering[Time]
sig Time {}
run {}
```

Only one instance is generated:

Instance #1

```
first returns: Time0
last returns: Time2
first.next returns: Time1
```

No more instances!

Lessons Learned

1. For a set created by enumerating its atoms, the ordering module orders the set in any way.
2. For a set created by a signature, the ordering module orders the set this way: Blah0, Blah1, Blah2, …, where “Blah” is the signature name.

I think the real lesson, however, is that the functions provided in the ordering module (`first, last, next, etc.`) make it *appear* that the set is ordered. But that is an illusion, it is just a view placed on top of the set. The set, in fact, has no ordering.

Do I have a correct understanding? Anything you would add to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this difference holds in 2 words: Symmetry breaking.
In short, Alloy wants to avoid returning isomorphic instances (instances which are the same up to label renaming).

Think of it that way:

When you analyze a model consisting solely of the signature one Time{} the analyzer will return a single instance composed of atom Time$0. Labeling this atom Time$1, Time$2 or CoolAtom won't change the fact that the instance is composed of a single atom of type Time.

When analyzing the model declaring Color as being either red, yellow or green, the analyzer will return 3 instances, each consisting of a different color.
Why you ask? That's because those atoms are semantically different in the sense that they do not have the same type.

Note that **in no ways you have created a set enumerating its atoms**. You have defined the set of colors as being composed of several sets (red, green, yellow) which all happen to have an arity of one.

Your final understanding however is correct in the sense that using ordering doesn't alter the essence of the signature it is used on (defining a set of atoms), but rather provides functions used to define an ordering on elements typed by the said signature.

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke the ordering module on some set S, you are simply adding an ordering to every instance, as if you explicitly included a homogeneous relation on the set S. As Loic notes, the key reason this is better than doing it explicitly is that you get symmetry breaking for free so better performance (and more convenient atom numbering). And of course, you don't need to axiomatize the ordering yourself.